Предлог "по сравнению с" надо ли выделять запятыми в этом предложении?
Хочется отметить, что (?) по сравнению с прошлым годом (?) мы набрали на 55 волонтеров больше.

Если выделять, то по какой причине?

не знаю, как лучше?

Правильно:
Хочется отметить, что по сравнению с прошлым годом мы набрали на 55 волонтеров больше.
Пояснение

Обстоятельственный оборот со значением сравнения в общем случае обособляется факультативно. Здесь мы учитываем малую распространенность оборота, поэтому обособления нет.

Вопросы могут возникнуть в связи с наличием союза ЧТО перед оборотом. Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, при этом союз ЧТО относится ко всему придаточному, в начале которого находится сравнительный оборот.

В Карте слов можно посмотреть  предложения такой же структуры, например:


Делали они так до тех пор, пока не пришли в точку, где измерили высоту того же полюса и обнаружили, что по сравнению с первым измерением она увеличилась на один градус. Земля плоская. Генеалогия ложной идеи, 2021.

Спасибо! А можете распространить оборот так, чтоб понадобилось его обособить? Именно в рамках этго предложения :)

Думаю, что не получится. Распространенность  — это общий фактор для решения задачи, но важнее оказалась позиция после союза ЧТО.  Можно посмотреть такой пример: «И всё же возможно, что по сравнению с тем существованием, которое вы ведёте в последнее время, условия покажутся терпимыми». Оборот значительно распространен, но запятой нет.

Если сравнить с придаточным условия, то там обособление разрешено: Он сказал, что, если будет свободен, вечером придёт ко мне; Но: Он сказал, что если будет свободен, то вечером придёт ко мне.  Даже здесь вставочная позиция придаточного не очень естественна, а в устной речи эту паузу не обозначить.  Чтобы показать целостность СПП, используется указ. слово ТО.
А оборот на практике вроде бы однозначно не обособляется после союза.

А возможна ли только одна запятая? Хочется отметить, что по сравнению с прошлым годом, мы набрали на 55 волонтеров больше.

Из примеров мы видим, что запятая не ставится. Можно сделать вывод, что запятой нет в  предложении: По сравнению с прошлым годом, мы набрали на 55 волонтеров больше. Оборот обособляется в середине предложения двумя запятыми как уточняющая информация.  В начале же предложения это будет актуализация оборота, то есть придание ему  дополнительного обст. значения, но для этого нет оснований.
